# Monitor log in real time for any of two specific lines

Tags: powershell

So I have a log file which will either get a line containing "deployment failed" or "deployment successful" ( it can be "30092002 - deployment failed for something") and after that do something.

I came up with this:

```
$keywords=Get-Content "keywords.txt"
Get-Content "the_log.log" -tail 1 -wait |
     ForEach-Object{
          foreach($word in $keywords){
               if($_ -contains $word){
                   echo "deployment completed"
               }
          }
     }
```

Content of keywords. txt

```
deployment failed
deployment successful
```

Then I have added a new line in the log ( just to simulate a realtime append).
It is working as expected.

However, when I add to the file something like the below it is not recognized and the echo does not work:

```
30092002-[XASE1353QEF] - deployment failed for something
```

How to make these keywords be like a wild card and detect them even if there is something on left or right of them and continue with the execution of the remaining part of the script?

Comment: The `-contains` operator works with an array as the LHS operand and tests if any array element is an exact, case-insensitive match for the RHS argument. For substring search use the `.Contains(substr)` method of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is all you need, as you said you only have 2 strings indicating a successfull or failed deployment and based on which one machtes you want to get a success or error message:

```
Get-Content [path] -tail 1 -wait | %{
    If ($_ -match "Single Sign On \[SSO\.zip\] deployment completed"){
        write-host "deployment completed"
    }
    ElseIf ($_ -match "Single Sign On \[SSO\.zip\] deployment failed"){
        write-error "deployment failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it and unfortunately does not work. No result is returned.

Comment: it works... once i add one of the keywords to the file i get the "deployments completed", maybe you were fast and did catch the first version i posted where I did a mistake?

Comment: Yes, it works if I add "deployment","completed","failed" in the keywords, but this returns results like "deployment started" as well. This is why I need one of the strings to be true "deployment completed" or "deployment failed".

Comment: ah ok u have one string for success and one for failed and based on which one matched you wanna get a success or a error message - right?

Comment: You were correct, it works. Unfortunately the keywords are more complex like : Single Sign On [SSO.zip] deployment completed". I think the brackets are messing with the regex as if I remove them, it works again.

Comment: so as we only have 2 strings to match we do not need a list of keywords.... I updated the code...

Comment: Just confirmed, the original one you gave is working, but the brackets I have are messing the things. The problem is that these brackets will always be present in the log as I have mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248479/discussion-between-delyan-and-toni).